# Inotifywait not working when using inside bash script

Tags: bash, inotify, inotify-tools

I am trying to make a bash script with `inotiy-tools` that will monitor a directory.

Here is my script

```
while f=$(inotifywait -m -e create -q -r "/media/data2/Music/English"  --format '%f %w')
do
    echo "$f"
done
```

The problem is when I run the above script it prints nothing on the terminal. I have checked the `inotifywait` command and it runs fine on terminal but why it is not working inside my script.

*inotifywait on terminal*

```
noob@noob:~$ inotifywait -m -e create -q -r /media/data2/Music/English  --format '%f %w'
hello /media/data2/Music/English/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `f=$(inotifywait...` waits for that command to end and only then gives you the output.

I rarely write bash, but you could try:

```
inotifywait .... |
while read line
do
    echo $line
done
```

Comment: Also can you point me to correct documentation which states that `$()` waits for that command to end and only then gives the output.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `-m` switch in that context, otherwise the `inotifywait` command will never return the control to the `while` loop.